# Polymorphic deserialization of XML using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml

I have an XML structure that can occur in one of two ways (the examples are just for purpose of explanation):

```
<User>
<Adress>Example Adress</Adress>
<Car>
<CarModel>Example car model</CarModel>
</Car>
</User>

<User>
<Adress>Example Adress</Adress>
<Motorcycle>
<MotorcycleModel>Example motorcycle model</MotorcycleModel>
</Motorcycle>
</User>
```

This is how I'm annotating the classes to try to allow polymorphic deserialization:

```
public class User {
    
    @JsonProperty("Address")
    public String address;

    public Vehicle vehicle;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Car.class, name="Car"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Motorcycle.class, name="Motorcycle")
})
public interface Vehicle {
    
}

public class Car implements Vehicle {
    
    @JsonProperty("CarModel")
    public String carModel;
}

public class Motorcycle implements Vehicle {
    
    @JsonProperty("MotorcycleModel")
    public String motorcycleModel;
}
```

However when I deserialize the XML string using xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString, User.class), the resulting Vehicle from User object is null when casted into a Car or Motorcycle. How should I annotate the classes to allow polymorphic deserialization to occur in this example?